# regedit to run in script, not in background

Tags: regedit

Is there a way for regedit to run in script, not in background.
With /e (export) it runs in background and returns control to the console (and would return control to a script as well, i think). I want to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REG.EXE

> REG.EXE does almost everything
> Regedt32 can do, but it allows you to
> do it from a command line. This can be
> useful when you want to quickly make a
> change without opening Regedt32, and
> it also allows you to embed registry
> operations in logon scripts and batch
> files.

Lots of info from the ever useful [Petri](https://web.archive.org/web/20100406074120/http://www.petri.co.il/reg_command_in_windows_xp.htm)

Comment: `reg.exe` already comes with Windows XP and later.

Comment: even better then :)